# CartoDB: add infowindow to layer?

Tags: javascript, cartodb

I am trying to add an infowindow on click and hover to a CartoDB map, [following this example](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/blob/develop/examples/custom_infowindow.html) and [the documentation](https://carto.com/docs/faqs/infowindows/#creating-an-infowindow-with-the-createlayer-function), but I am struggling.

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script type="infowindow/html" id="infowindow_template">
  <span> custom </span>
  <div class="cartodb-popup">
    <a href="#close" class="cartodb-popup-close-button close">x</a>
     <div class="cartodb-popup-content-wrapper">
       <div class="cartodb-popup-content">
         <h4>{{content.data.postcode}}</h4>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="cartodb-popup-tip-container"></div>
  </div>
</script>
```

And this is my JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var options = {
    center: [53.2, 0.0],
    zoom: 5
  };
  var map_object = new L.Map('map', options);
  var cartocss = '#combined { marker-fill-opacity: 0.9; marker-line-color: #FFF;marker-line-width: 1;marker-line-opacity: 1; marker-placement: point; marker-type: ellipse; marker-width: 10; marker-fill: #FF6600; marker-allow-overlap: true; }';
  cartodb.createLayer(map_object, {
    user_name: 'myname',
    type: 'cartodb',
    sublayers: [
      {
        type: "http",
        urlTemplate: "http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
        subdomains: [ "a", "b", "c" ]
      },
      {
       sql: 'SELECT * FROM combined',
       cartocss: cartocss
     },
    ]
  })
  .addTo(map_object)
  .on('done', function(layer) {
    var sublayer = layer.getSubLayer(1);
    cartodb.vis.Vis.addInfowindow(map_object, sublayer, [ 'postcode'], {
    infowindowTemplate: $('#infowindow_template').html(),
    templateType: 'mustache'
    });
  })
   .error(function(err) {
       console.log("error: " + err);
   });
});
```

This shows my points on a map, but when I click on them nothing happens. There is no error in the console. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: Oddly, if I delete the first layer and change the sublayer selector to `var sublayer = layer.getSubLayer(0)`, then the infowindows appear. But I do need both layers!

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `interactivity` to your second sublayer containing the fields you want to display on the infowindow, and again `setInteraction` to `true`. [Here](https://bl.ocks.org/oriolbx/3950e1a9b458a9177f9c) you have a working example.